# Authorization denied when I make a request to manage.office.com api

Tags: azure, office365api

I got a trial account for office365 and azure AD. I want to extract logs from office365 management activity api. I have registered my app in azure AD and also granted the following permissions to office365 management apis:

Application permissions:

- Read activity data for your organization
- Read service health information for your organization

Delegated Permissions

- Read activity data for your organization
- Read service health information for your organization

Through python adal library I am able to connect to graph.windows.net and grab the azure AD activity logs. More specifically this api call works

https://graph.windows.net/a51f6ada-7226-48b2-9bb6-2ec67e4f0720/activities/audit?api-version=beta&`$filter=activityDate gt 2017-06-24T12:56:07Z

When I try the same for the below api call
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/a51f6ada-7226-48b2-9bb6-2ec67e4f0720/activity/feed//subscriptions/list

I get b'{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}'

The decoded access_token is as follows:

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "9FXDpbfMFT2SvQuXh846YTwEIBw",
 kid: "9FXDpbfMFT2SvQuXh846YTwEIBw"
}.
{
 aud: "https://manage.office.com/",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/a51f6ada-7226-48b2-9bb6-2ec67e4f0720/",
 iat: 1498936727,
 nbf: 1498936727,
 exp: 1498940627,
 aio: "Y2ZgYFAWErggrrVm/pcvD42z7255BgA=",
 appid: "0c2cd016-7051-4814-8505-c75f6591064e",
 appidacr: "1",
 e_exp: 262800,
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/a51f6ada-7226-48b2-9bb6-2ec67e4f0720/",
 oid: "6c7a138d-8f78-49b8-ba87-52cffea5d2d6",
 roles: [
  "ServiceHealth.Read",
  "ActivityFeed.Read"
 ],
 sub: "6c7a138d-8f78-49b8-ba87-52cffea5d2d6",
 tid: "a51f6ada-7226-48b2-9bb6-2ec67e4f0720",
 ver: "1.0"
}.
[signature]
```

I have been struggling to solve this for the last 3 days. Went through a lot of documentation and examples.

Help is greatly appreciated.